# sending a list through RedirectToRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a Razor application with a model view controller structure, and I try to edit something then use redirect to route to return to an index page, but I try to pass the errors as well, as a list of strings.

I have something like this:

```
var errorMessages = new List<string>();
{...}
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action",  errorMessages = errorMessages });
```

and this is how my other controller method looks like:

```
public ActionResult Action(List<string> errorMessages)
{
...
}
```

the problem is that whatever happens in my firs controller, in the `Action` method I always get a collection with one element which reads `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]"`. whereas I'm expecting to receive the actual collection.

Any ideas why this happens? or how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to populate the `RouteValueDictionary` with a list of items.  Right now, all you're doing is setting `errorMessages` to the name of the type `List<string>`.

In order to fix this, you need to populate the `RouteValueDictionary` manually, ensuring that you do it in a format the default model binder will expect.  That means that, in order to bind to a collection, you need to pass it a list of items in the format:

```
errorMessages[0]
errorMessages[1]
...
errorMessages[n]
```

To relate to why this is necessary, read Phil Haack's blog post: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  Here's a simple example that shows you how to do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var errorMessages = new List<string>() { "test", "test2" };

        RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary()
        {
            { "controller", "home" },
            { "action", "action" }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < errorMessages.Count; i++)
            rvd["errorMessages[" + i + "]"] = errorMessages[i];

        return RedirectToRoute("Default", rvd);
    }

    public ActionResult Action(List<string> errorMessages)
    {
        // Do stuff

        return View();
    }
}
```

The `errorMessages` parameter for `Action` will now contain values for `test` and `test2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TempData`.

In action method you should save your messages into the `TempData`

```
var errorMessages = new List<string>();
{...}
TempData["Errors"] = errorMessages;
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" });
```

And then you can get it in Razor view page or action

```
@{
    var errorMessages = TempData["Errors"] as List<string>;
}

<ul>
@foreach(var errorMessage in errorMessages ){
    <li>@errorMessage</li>
}
</ul>
```

Read about it here http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications